# Eating fruit is not so healthy?

Tags: nutrition, fruits

I've noticed many articles claiming that fructose is worse for person's health than glucose, leading to various health problems in the long run.

For example, [this article](http://realfoodforager.com/fructose-how-much-is-safe/) suggests that:

> While much of the research into this question is obscure, a growing body of research suggests that greater than **50 grams of fructose a day** is detrimental and may start to cause Metabolic Syndrome and all the consequent problems.
>
> However, some suggest that **25 grams** should be the limit, and for people with known Metabolic Syndrome or it’s risk factors, **15 grams** of fructose a day.

There is also a table below which shows the amount of fructose in common fruits:

- Lemons, 1 medium, **0.6** grams of fructose
- Strawberries, 1 cup, **3.8** grams of fructose
- Banana, 1 medium, **7.1** grams of fructose
- Apple, 1 medium, **9.5** grams of fructose
- Figs, dried, 1 cup, **23.0** grams of fructose

Ok, don't eat dried fruits, I get it, but I was surprised by how high in the list an ordinary apple is. I always had an impression apples are among the healthiest fruits, with lots of fiber and (what I believed) not so much sugar!

Now it turns out that eating, say, 2 apples and 1 banana adds up to ~26 grams of fructose, and actually breaks the (slightly more conservative) "healthy" threshold of 25 grams a day?

Comment: Not so healthy in terms of fructose/sugars, but that's only one dimension of "healthy". I'm wondering if someone can actually point to some sources that show that just eating more fruit is healthy. Last time I checked almost all studies had fruits lumped into one category with vegetables.

Comment: @VonBeche: that's correct, it's often the phrase "eat more fruits and vegetables" that's associated with healthy nutrition, but I wonder if the "fruit" part is still problematic?

Comment: "More" would be going from 0 to 1-3 pieces of fruit a day for the average American, so in general you're still in the right fructose range (as long as you cut HFCS soda first).

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of facts:

- Fructose is not only in fruits, but also in table sugar (sucrose), which is glucose + fructose, and thus in many sweetened foods.
- Various fruits contain fructose, glucose and sucrose in various proportions. Fruits high in fructose are apples, pears, mangoes, grapes, agave, watermelon and others (check on [Nutrientsreview.com](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/carbs/monosaccharides-fructose.html))

Conclusions of some studies:

1. Fructose and metabolic syndrome: [Metabolic Effects of Fructose and the Worldwide Increase in Obesity (Physiological Reviews, 2010)](http://physrev.physiology.org/content/90/1/23.long)

> ...fructose intake >50 g/day...was associated with increased
>   postprandial triglyceride excursions...
>
> There is, however, no unequivocal evidence that fructose intake at
>   moderate doses is directly related with adverse metabolic effects.

So, >50 g/day of fructose can raise triglycerides, but this alone is not already metabolic syndrome.

2. Fructose and obesity. [A critical examination of the evidence relating high fructose corn syrup and weight gain.
   (PubMed, 2007)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17653981)

> Based on the currently available evidence, the expert panel concluded
>   that HFCS does not appear to contribute to overweight and obesity any
>   differently than do other energy sources

I posted only 2 studies, which represent what I believe: Fructose does not contribute to metabolic syndrome and obesity (significantly) more than glucose or other energy sources (proteins, fats).